# Rails - How to select data from database and print them out by day?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I am trying to come up with an idea how to print out data from database in following format:

```
January 25
- record 1
- record 2
- record 3
- record 4
- record ...

January 26
- record 1
- record 2
- record 3
- record 4
- record ...

...
```

Is there any way to do it with ActiveRecord?
My only idea is to fetched data from database (`@data = Model.order(created_at DESC).limit(50)`), then in the respective view to have a help-variable where I would keep the current data and when in the loop through `@data` would a record has a different date than the one in the help-variable, I would save this new date to the help-variable and continue in the looping.

But this is not very clear and elegant and, there might be a problem that I will print out a date and there will be no data from `@data` to be printed out, like this:

January 25
    - record 1
    - record 2
    - record 3
    - record 4
    - record ...

```
January 26
- record 1
- record 2
- record 3
- record 4
- record ...

January 27
[nothing here]
```

What's the best approach to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The transformation you want is called grouping. There is a [special method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) for that in Ruby. In your case, you can do

```ruby
Model.order(created_at: :desc).limit(50).group_by { |record| record.created_at.to_date }
```

Also, note the `order(created_at: :desc)`; it's a syntactic sugar for your SQL.

Comment: Thank you @shock_one, I am testing the query, but when I try to loop through the data in the view, I get following error: `undefined method `name' for #<Array:0x007f8953255fd8>` - do I need to convert the data in the view?

Comment: @user984621, the resulting hash will be `{date => [record1, record2, ...], date2 => [...]}`. So, you need to iterate over the array, and call `name` on its elements.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want to print out items for the last one month.

```
@items = Model.all    
date_today = Date.today 
# if you want for the last one week
# this_week = (date_today.at_beginning_of_week..date_today.at_end_of_week).map.each { |day| day }
this_month = (date_today.at_beginning_of_month..date_today.at_end_of_month).map.each { |day| day }
this_month.each do |month_day|
   day = month_day.to_date
   puts "#{day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}:"
   @data = items.select{|i| i.visit_date.to_date == day}.limit(10) 
   #loop through every item 
   @data.each {|d| puts "#{ d}}
end
```

you can write a cleaner code. I hope that helps.